# Animate spinning circle(percentage) with css

Tags: html, css, css-animations

How can i make the spinning circles which is on the following site http://www.awwwards.com/

For my site i don't need it to be dynamic. At least not this time. I have tried out different solutions, with both Javascript and CSS, but i'm not sure what is the best method to create this.

```
-moz-transform: rotate(270);
-webkit-transform: rotate(270);
-o-transform:rotate(270deg);
transform: rotate(270deg);
transition: all 2s;
```

This is pretty much all i know about transitions, but i guess its enough. However, i would have to have my "pie" of the cake cut out before the transition start, right?

Anyone know where i should start?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can read this article and see a working example and even understand how it works [css-pie-timer](http://css-tricks.com/css-pie-timer/)

**UPDATE**

I didn't like that solution so I tried to implement it my self and with a little help (I asked few questions here) I manage to do it pretty elegant.

The main idea is to understand how to draw a circle sector and then start drawing section with degree = 0 until you reach degree you want.

I also made it reversible, just for fun :).

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="activeBorder" class="active-border">
        <div id="circle" class="circle">
            <span class="prec 270" id="prec">0%</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The active border will be replaced with the current percentage. The prec span will contains the textual percentage and also the total degrees you want (270) in this example. As I implemented it, the percentage needs to be the second class.

**CSS**

This is the tricky part. This is the tricky part. I draw the sector this way:

```
.active-border{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color:#39B4CC;
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(91deg, transparent 50%, #A2ECFB 50%),
        linear-gradient(90deg, #A2ECFB 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

Explanation: the first `linear-gradient` value will be the degrees shown + 90.
If the degrees is bigger than 180 we'll set the first `linear-gradient` color to our active color.

**JQuery**

```
function loopit(dir){
    // choose direction
    if (dir == "c")
        i++
    else
        i--;
    // stop condition
    if (i < 0)
        i = 0;
    if (i > degs)
        i = degs;

    // calculate and set the percentage text
    prec = (100*i)/360;   
    $(".prec").html(Math.round(prec)+"%");

    if (i<=180){
        activeBorder.css('background-image','linear-gradient(' + (90+i) + 'deg, transparent 50%, #A2ECFB 50%),linear-gradient(90deg, #A2ECFB 50%, transparent 50%)');
    }
    else{
        activeBorder.css('background-image','linear-gradient(' + (i-90) + 'deg, transparent 50%, #39B4CC 50%),linear-gradient(90deg, #A2ECFB 50%, transparent 50%)');
    }

    // recursive call 
    setTimeout(function(){
        if($("#circle").is(":hover"))
           loopit("c");
        else
           loopit("nc");
    },1); 
}
```

And here's a **[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zap4f/1/)**

**Note** It works for firefox and chrome. You'll have to add IE support for `linear-gradient`.

Comment: how can i make it stop at a certain point? Lets say at 290deg. If i change the demo to 290 you can see what i ended up with the first time i tried doing this.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nIDeH

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gHxDb

latest. now to make it stop at a certain degree

Comment: @sindrem look at my second solution

Comment: I do have one problem wtih this tho! On safari(mac atleast) and mobile the number increasing sometimes stop before it really should. If i mark the text, the number shows correctly. Seems more like a graphical error tbh, but is there any way i can manually update the number after the circle is complete?

Comment: Do you know what i can do to make it work on mobile\safari? @Itay Gal

Comment: I'm not sure how hover works with mobile,  you can add a JQuery code that changes the inner HTML of your circle once the animation ends. It should work.

Comment: Im not using the hover function, but im not sure how i can know if the function is done running.

Comment: @user3396867 In the beginning of loopit function, you can increment i by 2 or 3 instead of 1, this will the animation faster.

Answer (score 3):

I liked Itay Gal's answer because of its simplicity, using only CSS and Javascript.

I was able to simplify it further, and also made it more of a real world example, so that it runs whenever the function is called (at startup or whenever you call it). Simply pass in the percentage number where you want it to stop.

Works in all modern browsers, including IE10+. Degrades gracefully in older browsers.

JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ggj55sqo/

**HTML**

```
<div id="sellPerCirc" class="perCirc">
    <div class="perCircInner">
        <div class="perCircStat">0%</div><div>Complete</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.perCirc {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #00cc00;
    background-image: linear-gradient(91deg, transparent 50%, #ccc 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, #ccc 50%, transparent 50%);
}
.perCirc .perCircInner {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.perCirc .perCircInner div {
    position: relative;
    top: 22px;
    color:#777;
}
.perCirc .perCircStat {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height:1em;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
// change the value below from 80 to whichever percentage you want it to stop at.
perCirc($('#sellPerCirc'), 80);

function perCirc($el, end, i) {
    if (end < 0)
        end = 0;
    else if (end > 100)
        end = 100;
    if (typeof i === 'undefined')
        i = 0;
    var curr = (100 * i) / 360;
    $el.find(".perCircStat").html(Math.round(curr) + "%");
    if (i <= 180) {
        $el.css('background-image', 'linear-gradient(' + (90 + i) + 'deg, transparent 50%, #ccc 50%),linear-gradient(90deg, #ccc 50%, transparent 50%)');
    } else {
        $el.css('background-image', 'linear-gradient(' + (i - 90) + 'deg, transparent 50%, #00cc00 50%),linear-gradient(90deg, #ccc 50%, transparent 50%)');
    }
    if (curr < end) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            perCirc($el, end, ++i);
        }, 1);
    }
}
```